# How to remove background layer of an <img> when using object-fit: contain;

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, cut

I am trying to make image viewer, which has overlay window with div in the center and inside the div an image that scales up and down on window resize that keeps its default ratio by using object-fit: contain; which is working ok. The problem is that when using object-fit: contain; it scales the content of the  and the  has someting like background layer which stops me from clicking on the overlay window so I can close the view. Is it possible to crop, cut auto resize the  so it is always big as the content. Maybe using clip:rect();. Thanks in advance.

**I am trying to remove the blue background so I can click on the background and close the overlay window, but still keep the ability to click on the image without closing the overlay.**

[image]

**Example**: https://jsfiddle.net/qwdnkxLt/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Show Image</title>

    <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            /* --scrollbarBG: rgb(70, 103, 109);
            --thumbBG: rgba(81, 74, 85, 0.78); */
        }




        /*--------BODY--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: rgb(40, 37, 44);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }


        /* --------Content - Item---IMG-----*/
        .contentContainer_Item {
            /* width: 250px;
            height: 150px; */

            width: 17em;
            height: 10em;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10pt 3pt rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* filter: drop-shadow(0 0.2rem 0.25rem rgb(0, 0, 0)); */
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: solid 2px rgb(17, 17, 22);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            display: block;
        }






        .contentContainer_Item:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 5pt 2pt rgba(33, 182, 216, 0.39);
            border: solid 2px rgb(29, 221, 189);
            border-radius: 5px;
            filter: saturate(3)
        }







        .contentContainer_Item_Margin {
            margin: 20px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            color: rgb(5, 163, 255);
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }



        .contentContainer_Item_Margin:hover {
            color: rgb(5, 255, 255);
        }







        .contentContainer_Item_Holder {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }



        .contentContainer_Item_Holder_Image_Viewer {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 4;
            bottom: 50px;
            right: 30px;
            cursor: zoom-in;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 217, 255, 0.811);
            border: 1px solid rgb(112, 197, 236);

        }

        img.view-Img-Button {
            content: url('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-142984111.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!--Overlay-Window------------------------------->
    <div id="overlayWindow" onmousedown="this.style.display='none';"
        style="display: none; background-color: rgba(9, 21, 34, 0.7); position: fixed; z-index: 100;  background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/environment-earth-day-hands-trees-growing-seedlings-bokeh-green-background-female-hand-holding-tree-nature-field-gra-130247647.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;  background-size: 100% 100%;  width: 100%; height: 100%;  top: 0; left: 0;  bottom: 0; right: 0;">


        <!--Overlay--WIndow-Content--Container------------------------------>
        <div  style="position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%;  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color:rgb(255, 168, 68); width: 80%;  height: 80%;"> 
            <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg"
                style="position: absolute; border-radius: 100px;  background-color:rgba(24, 129, 190, 0.938); object-fit: contain;  width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
        </div>

    </div>




    <!--Holder::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-------------------------------->
    <div class="contentContainer_Item_Holder">
        <!--Img Viewer Button-------------------------------->
        <img onmousedown="ViewImage('calcArea')"
            class="view-Img-Button contentContainer_Item_Holder_Image_Viewer"></img>

        <!--Img---------------------------------------------->
        <a href="https://github.com/stefan27dk/AutoFOCUS" target="_blank" class="contentContainer_Item_Margin">
            <img id="calcAreaThumb" alt="Calc. Area of Graf" class="contentContainer_Item"></img>
            Calc. Area of graf - "JS"</a>
    </div>






    <!---Images--Storage------------------------------------------------>
    <script>
        var calcArea = 'https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/lightroom-cc/how-to/share-photos-on-web-gallery/_jcr_content/main-pars/image/share-photos-on-web-gallery_1800x1012.jpg';
        document.getElementById('calcAreaThumb').style.content = `url(${calcArea})`;
    </script>




    <!---Overlay Window---::JS::--------------------------------------------->
    <script>
        function ViewImage(imgName) {
            document.getElementById("overlayWindow").style.display = 'block'; // Show overlayWindow
            document.getElementById('overlayImg').src = window[imgName]; // Static img Tag
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Setting the position of any object to `absolute` is a little dangerous: it makes it ignore almost any relationship it has with other objects regarding position, scale etc.

As such, I would recommend using `position: relative;` for your image container and allowing one of the two dimensions (I recommend using `height: 100%` and `width: inherit` or `auto`) to scale automatically to maintain the aspect ratio. Modern browsers are smart enough to usually fill in the area given properly without leaving any gaps.
Also, remember to use `margin: auto;` to center your objects nicely.

This should solve your problem:

```
<!--Overlay--WIndow-Content--Container------------------------------>
<div  style="display: block; position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%;  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color:rgb(255, 168, 68); width: auto;  height: 80%;"> 
    <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg"
        style="
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-color:rgba(24, 129, 190, 0.938);
        object-fit: contain;
        width: inherit;
        height: 100%;
        " />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uewog42m/25/

A final thought: it is easier to debug if you keep your CSS and HTML/JS separate! Consider using a separate stylesheet for all your CSS code.

### Solution 2

Another way to approach this problem, is to use a container for the image and use it for the scaling. Then, place the image inside the container and use the parent's dimensions. Last, cut the overflow (if any).
Or if you don't want to cut part of the image, don't use max values for the width/height and center the image.

It should look something like this:

```
<!--Overlay--WIndow-Content--Container------------------------------>
<div  style="display: block; position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%;  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color:rgb(255, 168, 68); width: auto;  height: 80%;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
    ">
        <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg"
            style="
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            background-color:rgba(24, 129, 190, 0.938);
            object-fit: contain;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        " />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and thanks for the advices. I tried out your solution but now the image is not resizing when I resize the browser window it stays the maximum size. Regards.

Comment: Resizing inside the JSFiddle is working. Are you sure nothing else is affecting the image in your project? Also, have you tried different browsers to see if it is a browser-specific issue?

Comment: @Stefan27 I have updated my answer by adding another solution. Please make sure to provide more information if the problem persists.

Comment: Its really strange. I use Brave Browser. The first solution does not resize the image and the second resizes the image but I have long screen 2560 x 1080 and in maximized window the image is over sized. But I got it working by using max-width: 80vw; and height. I think your second solution will work for me too I will just need to set max-width and height. Thanks so much for the help you are really fast at the replaying.You helped me solve the problem. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution that worked for me:**
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Show Image</title>

    <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            /* --scrollbarBG: rgb(70, 103, 109);
            --thumbBG: rgba(81, 74, 85, 0.78); */
        }




        /*--------BODY--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: rgb(40, 37, 44);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }


        /* --------Content - Item---IMG-----*/
        .contentContainer_Item {
            /* width: 250px;
            height: 150px; */

            width: 17em;
            height: 10em;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10pt 3pt rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* filter: drop-shadow(0 0.2rem 0.25rem rgb(0, 0, 0)); */
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: solid 2px rgb(17, 17, 22);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            display: block;
        }






        .contentContainer_Item:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 5pt 2pt rgba(33, 182, 216, 0.39);
            border: solid 2px rgb(29, 221, 189);
            border-radius: 5px;
            filter: saturate(3)
        }







        .contentContainer_Item_Margin {
            margin: 20px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            color: rgb(5, 163, 255);
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }



        .contentContainer_Item_Margin:hover {
            color: rgb(5, 255, 255);
        }







        .contentContainer_Item_Holder {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }



        .contentContainer_Item_Holder_Image_Viewer {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 4;
            bottom: 50px;
            right: 30px;
            cursor: zoom-in;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 217, 255, 0.811);
            border: 1px solid rgb(112, 197, 236);

        }

        img.view-Img-Button {
            content: url('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-142984111.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!--Overlay-Window------------------------------->
    <div id="overlayWindow" onmousedown="this.style.display='none';"
        style="
        display: none; 
        background-color: 
        rgba(9, 21, 34, 0.7);
         position: fixed; 
         z-index: 100;  
         background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/environment-earth-day-hands-trees-growing-seedlings-bokeh-green-background-female-hand-holding-tree-nature-field-gra-130247647.jpg) 
         no-repeat center center fixed;  
         background-size: 100% 100%;  
         width: 100%; 
         height: 100%;  
         top: 0; 
         left: 0;  
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;">


        <!--Overlay--WIndow-Content--Container------------------------------>
        <div  style="display: block; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 50%; 
        left: 50%;  
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        background-color:rgb(255, 168, 68);
        max-width: 80vw;
        max-height: 80vh"> 


            <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg"
        style="
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-color:rgba(24, 129, 190, 0.938);
        object-fit: contain;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 80vh;
        max-width: 80vw;
        " />
        </div>

    </div>




    <!--Holder::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-------------------------------->
    <div class="contentContainer_Item_Holder">
        <!--Img Viewer Button-------------------------------->
        <img onmousedown="ViewImage('calcArea')"
            class="view-Img-Button contentContainer_Item_Holder_Image_Viewer"></img>

        <!--Img---------------------------------------------->
        <a href="https://github.com/stefan27dk/AutoFOCUS" target="_blank" class="contentContainer_Item_Margin">
            <img id="calcAreaThumb" alt="Calc. Area of Graf" class="contentContainer_Item"></img>
            Calc. Area of graf - "JS"</a>
    </div>






    <!---Images--Storage------------------------------------------------>
    <script>
        var calcArea = 'https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/lightroom-cc/how-to/share-photos-on-web-gallery/_jcr_content/main-pars/image/share-photos-on-web-gallery_1800x1012.jpg';
        document.getElementById('calcAreaThumb').style.content = `url(${calcArea})`;
    </script>




    <!---Overlay Window---::JS::--------------------------------------------->
    <script>
        function ViewImage(imgName) {
            document.getElementById("overlayWindow").style.display = 'block'; // Show overlayWindow
            document.getElementById('overlayImg').src = window[imgName]; // Static img Tag
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Snippet:**

```
<!--Overlay--WIndow-Content--Container------------------------------>
        <div  style="display: block; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 50%; 
        left: 50%;  
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        background-color:rgb(255, 168, 68);
        max-width: 80vw;
        max-height: 80vh"> 


            <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg"
        style="
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-color:rgba(24, 129, 190, 0.938);
        object-fit: contain;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 80vh;
        max-width: 80vw;
        " />
        </div>
```

**Even cleaner without the extra Div:**

```
    <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg" style="
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(83, 82, 99);
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;  
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    max-height: 80vh;
    max-width: 80vw;
    " />
```

So actully I dont need object-fit: contain; but only

```
    max-height: 80vh; 
    max-width: 80vw;
```

and for small images to be resized up

```
    min-height:auto;
    min-width:  50vh;
```

Cant believe it was simple as that. It resizes on window resize and keeps its Ratio, have tested with 16:9, 1:1 and 9:16.

**FULLY WORKING CODE:----------------------------------------------------------**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Show Image</title>

    <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            /* --scrollbarBG: rgb(70, 103, 109);
            --thumbBG: rgba(81, 74, 85, 0.78); */
        }




        /*--------BODY--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: rgb(40, 37, 44);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }


        /* --------Content - Item---IMG-----*/
        .contentContainer_Item {
            /* width: 250px;
            height: 150px; */

            width: 17em;
            height: 10em;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10pt 3pt rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* filter: drop-shadow(0 0.2rem 0.25rem rgb(0, 0, 0)); */
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: solid 2px rgb(17, 17, 22);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            display: block;
            object-fit: contain;

        }






        .contentContainer_Item:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 5pt 2pt rgba(33, 182, 216, 0.39);
            border: solid 2px rgb(29, 221, 189);
            border-radius: 5px;
            filter: saturate(3)
        }







        .contentContainer_Item_Margin {
            margin: 20px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            color: rgb(5, 163, 255);
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }



        .contentContainer_Item_Margin:hover {
            color: rgb(5, 255, 255);
        }







        .contentContainer_Item_Holder {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }



        .contentContainer_Item_Holder_Image_Viewer {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 4;
            bottom: 50px;
            right: 30px;
            cursor: zoom-in;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 217, 255, 0.811);
            border: 1px solid rgb(112, 197, 236);

        }

        img.view-Img-Button {
            content: url('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-142984111.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!--Overlay-Window------------------------------->
    <div id="overlayWindow" onmousedown="this.style.display='none';" style="
         display: none; 
         background-color:rgba(9, 21, 34, 0.7);
         position: fixed; 
         z-index: 100;  
         width: 100%; 
         height: 100%;  
         top: 0; 
         left: 0;  
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;">




        <img onmousedown="event.stopPropagation();" id="overlayImg" style="
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(83, 82, 99);
        top: 50%; 
        left: 50%;  
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        max-height: 80vh;
        max-width: 80vw;
        min-height:auto;
        min-width:  50vw;
        " />
    </div>




    <!--Holder::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-------------------------------->
    <div class="contentContainer_Item_Holder">
        <!--Img Viewer Button-------------------------------->
        <img onmousedown="ViewImage('calcArea')"
            class="view-Img-Button contentContainer_Item_Holder_Image_Viewer"></img>

        <!--Img---------------------------------------------->
        <a href="https://github.com/stefan27dk/AutoFOCUS" target="_blank" class="contentContainer_Item_Margin">
            <img id="calcAreaThumb" alt="Calc. Area of Graf" class="contentContainer_Item"></img>
            Calc. Area of graf - "JS"</a>
    </div>






    <!---Images--Storage------------------------------------------------>
    <script>
        var calcArea = 'https://store-guides2.djicdn.com/guides/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Justen-Soule-Sunrise-Lake-Wake-Inspire-1-1.jpg';
        document.getElementById('calcAreaThumb').style.content = `url(${calcArea})`;
    </script>




    <!---Overlay Window---::JS::--------------------------------------------->
    <script>
        function ViewImage(imgName) {
            document.getElementById("overlayWindow").style.display = 'block'; // Show overlayWindow
            document.getElementById('overlayImg').src = window[imgName]; // Static img Tag
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```